# FPS drop when the focus is in another windows

Tags: c#, windows, focus, frame-rate

I have a WinForm application, with properties `TopLevel` and `TopMost` set to true. Then I have a GameProcess, my application is over this game. Like the next picture.

[image]

From time to time I have to interactive for 1 or 2 seconds with the WinForm application, so when I got the focus in this windows, the FPS drops in the GameProcess.exe due to the focus, which it totally makes sense.

Nevertheless I saw some kind of overlays that doesn't drop the FPS in other kind of applications, I'd like to know how they work, or how I can improve my WinForms to avoid the other non-focus windows to drop the FPS. Thanks!

Comment: You can try to run your pogramm in a higher priority class [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/scheduling-priorities)

Comment: Do you mean create an overlay like Overwolf or Discord? I believe that's done by DirectX hooking (or OpenGL for that matter).